How to export NFS share from WSL automatically mounted NTFS partition?
I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu. I installed NFS server. I have drive D:\ which is automatically mounted in WSL under /mnt/d. When I add this path to /etc/exports and issue sudo exportfs -a I get exportfs: /mnt/d/torrent does not support NFS export error. My export is declared as /mnt/d/torrent *(ro,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

I guess the Linux kernel provided by WSL doesn't support NFS.
